# How to receive input value from thymeleaf table?

Tags: jquery, thymeleaf

I fill table from Spring, with using Thymeleaf.

```
<tr th:each="customerOrder : ${selected}" >
         <td>
             <img th:attr="src=${customerOrder.photo}" width="80" height="56" />
         </td>
         <td align="center">
             <span th:text="${customerOrder.name}" >Name</span>
         </td>
         <td align="center" >
           <input type="text" name="quantityNew" th:value="${customerOrder.quantity}"/>          
         </td>
         <td align="center">
             <div class="editInfoFromCustomerOrder">
                 <input type="hidden" name="editOrderId" th:value="${customerOrder.id}"/>
                 <input type="button" value="Save edit"/>
             </div>
         </td>
</tr>
```

And I want to receive value from `<input type="hidden" name="editOrderId" th:value="${customerOrder.id}"/>`, but I don't understand why my code don't work. 
 I try to use this code:

```
 $('.editInfoFromCustomerOrder').on('click', function (e) {
    var orderId = $(this).find('input[name=editOrderId]').val();
    var quantityChange = $(this).find('input[type=text][name=quantityNew]').val();
    alert("OrderId: "+orderId+" Quantity: "+quantityChange);
  });
```

I receive value `orderId`, but don't receive `quantityChange`. 
Where my mistake?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.find()` only searches children of the element you are using it on.  Since `$(this)` is the div (which has a child element `name=editOrderId`) it will find that element.  Since `name=quantityNew` is outside of the div, it doesn't get matched.

In my opinion, you should be structuring these kind of calls more like this:

Javascript

```
$(function() {
  $('.save').click(function (e) {
    var id = $(this).data('customer-id');
    var quantity = $('#quantity-' + id).val();
    alert("OrderId: " + id + " Quantity: " + quantity);
  });
});
```

Html

```
  <tr th:each="customerOrder : ${selected}" >
    <td><img th:attr="src=${customerOrder.photo}" width="80" height="56" /></td>
    <td align="center" th:text="${customerOrder.name}" />
    <td align="center"><input type="text" th:id="${'quantity-' + customerOrder.id}" th:value="${customerOrder.quantity}"/></td>
    <td align="center"><input type="button" class="save" th:attr="data-customer-id = ${customerOrder.id}" value="Save edit"/></td>
  </tr>
```